# Problem installing Elementary os on a dual boot windows 7 configuration

Tags: system-installation

After completing the installation process, when I boot I am getting the following message:

The Disk Drive for `/dev/mapper/cryptswap1` is not ready yet or not present.

Continue to wait, or Press S to skip mounting or M for Manual Recovery

what can I do?

in the link below you can read the result of commands
    cat /etc/fstab
    lsblk
    pvs 
    vgs
    lvs

https://www.evernote.com/shard/s6/sh/b745d987-5f24-4bf3-9221-3a26f020537a/e68ec509774c0fc93b1e6e45ac85e4c8

I had Windows 7 installed, so I chose a dual boot installation from the elementary OS installation ISO.

Thanks you for your help!